# How to speed up minimax algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, minimax

I'm trying to figure out how to increase the speed of this algorithm. It works perfectly for two games (2-person games, CPU vs Human), but the problems is when I assign more than three piles (that contains a number of stones, so each player can pick up more than one), the computer player takes forever to compute the moves:

```
public Object[] minimax(int depth, int player) {

        if(hasPlayer1Won(player)){
            return new Object[]{get_default_input(1),1};
        }else if(hasPlayer2Won(player)){
            return new Object[]{get_default_input(1),-1};
        }
        List<T> movesAvailable = getNextStates();

        if(movesAvailable.isEmpty()){
            return new Object[]{get_default_input(0), 0};
        }
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        T computersMove = getNextStates().get(0);
        int i = 0;
        for (T move: movesAvailable) {
            makeAMove(move, player);
            Object[] result = minimax(depth + 1, player == G.PLAYER1 ? G.PLAYER2 : G.PLAYER1);
            int currentScore = (int)result[1];

            if(player == G.PLAYER1){
                max = Math.max(currentScore, max);

                if(currentScore >= 0 && depth == 0) {
                    computersMove = move;
                }
                if(currentScore == 1){
                    resetMove(move);
                    break;
                }
                if(i==movesAvailable.size() - 1  && max < 0){
                    if (depth == 0){
                        computersMove = move;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                min = Math.min(currentScore, min);
                if(min == -1) {
                    resetMove(move);
                    break;
                }
            }
            i++;
            resetMove(move);
        }

        return new Object[]{computersMove, player == G.PLAYER1 ? max: min};
    }
```

Comment: Do you know about [alpha-beta pruning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning)?

Comment: The classic way to improve the minimax algorithm is with alpha-beta pruning
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning

Comment: OK question, but how long is "forever"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sucessfully tested the following methods for improving minimax (used it to play Tic-Tac-Toe and Domineering):

1. [Alpha beta pruning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBXHtz4Gbdo) - used a special variant of this type of pruning, in conjunction with [Lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) - basically instead of generating the whole tree I just generated an optimal move on each layer and kept Lazy holders for the other state-action pairs (applying the Lazy evaluation method, by making use of a supplier and calling it when a move different than the one I held was made).
2. [Heuristic pruning](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397599000821) - see the chapter on heuristics in that book. I basically only generated the first d branches of the tree and instead of having a deterministic outcome, I applied the heuristic function described in that book to the current state to determine a heuristic outcome. Whenever move (d+1) was made, I generated another branch using the same approach. 
   Here, d is the level that you choose (safest way is by testing)
3. [Parallel computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) also have a look at this, you may find it harder to implement but it pays off

First 2 options brought me a lot of computational time save, such that I was able to play Domineering optimally up to a 5x5 board and heuristically up to 10x10 (it can be better depending on how well you want it to play).